# plotnine: How to caption?

Tags: python, plotnine

I have a [plot](https://units-helper.d8u.us/covid/2.svg) and I'd like to make the "source: JHU" line into a caption. There are a number of [issues](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/) some [open](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/177) and others [closed](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine/issues/313) regarding this in [plotnine's github](https://github.com/has2k1/plotnine).

It has been brought to my attention that if I move the axis label to the right and reduce the font size, I can approximate what I want. For the font size, I suppose I can get away with [element_text](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.themes.element_text.html). However, I cannot figure out how to make the axis label appear on the bottom right. Anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a hack, but within the `element_text` you can use the `ha` parameter and pass it the string "left" to make the label be offset to the right, but this only offsets it to the right of the center of the axis. So you can push it further to the right by adding space to the front by using something like `plotnine.labs('{:>50}'.format("source: JHU..."))` to make the label be any number of characters long (50 here) and aligned right.

Comment: Hacker of the Month award goes to...